# PostgreSQL query to C#

Tags: postgresql, c#, visual-studio

So I have this query in PostgreSQL:

```
SELECT * FROM "Database";
```

Which works great, but now I want to do a more complicated query and I have no idea how.

So how can I write this Query in C#:

```
SELECT * FROM "Database";
```

Comment: So, what's your question?

Comment: -1 because I found a solution in 3sec google search. See my answer. And actually it's also a bit off-topic.

Comment: This is an extremely inefficient query, not worthy of being ported. Naming a table "Database" is extremely poor practice. Using mixed case in object names is likely to cause pain. Given the level of detail you've provided about the first query, there doesn't seem to be much point to this Question.

Comment: you edited your question to be even more useless...

Comment: @RoVo I agree with your 2.ed comment but would call it more offtopic instead of useless... However **IMO** your first comment isn't valid because you have more experience in this field as OP and can, therefore, google more efficient and know the words you need to use in order to get meaningful results

Comment: On the point of searching, it also worth bearing in mind that Google personalizes search results, so what one person finds on the first page another may not find until many pages down.

Comment: I doubt the result of my [search query](https://www.google.com/search?q=c%23+multine+string) is in any way personalized. Also there is no fancy word or anything I needed to use ... This is the very basics, otherwise maybe OP should not code in C# in the first place.

Answer (score 4):

Use this:

```
return @"SELECT ST_AsGeoJSON(ST_Transform(geom, 32633)) 
    FROM ""Database"" 
    WHERE ST_Distance(ST_Transform(geom, 32633),
    ST_SetSRID(ST_Point(536251.378984788,5211860.67521085), 32633)) < 100";
```

(This is called [Verbatim string literal](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/string))

([via](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1100260/multiline-string-literal-in-c-sharp))